# Neo4j add algorithm to library

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-algorithm

Is there a way to add a graph processing algorithm to the `Neo4j` database engine without rewriting the `algorithms` module? I can do it in an external process (i.e. implementing a ruby script or java program that retrieves the nodes and processes them) but I'd like it to be inside the DB engine for encapsulation and availability.

Namely, can I implement a search algorithm that includes adding tags to nodes as I travel through them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean.  Neo4J provides for [unmanaged extensions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) which you can use to do what I think you're trying to do.

There is also the idea of [server plugins](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html) which you can explore.   Which thing would be right for you to do would depend on what you want to accomplish with that "external process".

Warning - the use of those APIs may be a less elegant way to go about what you want to do, as the APIs may change.  You might be better off asking a different question that outlines the specifics of what you're trying to accomplish, and then asking for guidance on the best design way to do that.   But the answer to your question I think is that fundamentally adding things to the database engine without rewriting the algorithms module is possible, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it's the best way to accomplish whatever you want to do.

Comment: Server plugins are what I was searching for. Thanks.